# open port 443 vCenter server

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

Thank you so much for looking at my.  I am trying to open up ports 443 and 80 for access to the vCenter server by a disaster recovering software.  The disaster recovery site is located in the different state and we have vpn tunnel between two sites with ports 443 & 80 open.  The disaster recovery site is an esx host 5.0.

I ran **nmap ping** to check on ports 443 & 80 to esx host:

**Port 443**

> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-10 11:26 Central
>   Daylight Time Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xx.xx Host is up (0.0079s
>   latency). PORT    STATE SERVICE
>   443/tcp open  https
>
> Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 24.41 seconds

**Port 80**

> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-10 11:27 Central
>   Daylight Time Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xx.xx Host is up (0.0098s
>   latency). PORT   STATE SERVICE
>   80/tcp open  http
>
> Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.52 seconds

Now, when I do the same thing for vCenter, I get this:

**Port 443**

> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-10 11:12 Central
>   Daylight Time Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xx.xx Host is up (0.0078s
>   latency). PORT    STATE  SERVICE 443/tcp closed https
>
> Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 7.11 seconds

**Port 80**

> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-10 11:13 Central
>   Daylight Time Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xx.xx Host is up (0.0079s
>   latency). PORT   STATE  SERVICE 80/tcp closed http
>
> Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.38 seconds

I also attempted to run **esxcfg-firewall --openPort ,tcp|udp,in|out,** to open up the ports, but I don't believe this command applies to esx 5.0.

I know I might be missing some important info, so please, please, ask follow ups.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Is vCenter running on Windows, or are you using the Appliance?

Comment: Yes, it's running on Windows with Windows firewall turned off

Comment: What device are you doing nmap from?

Comment: @CIA One of the helpers from data recovery site, but it looks the same on the source site

Comment: Just to confirm; You ran nmap from a computer at the recovery site to both destinations to get the results above?  I read Chopper3's answer below and he is correct; 80 and 443 are used by the vCenter server's website(s). Even so, they should report open. 902 is generally reserved for communicating with other applications, like backup software (e.g. BackupExec).  Try: `nc –z <vcenter ip> <port range>` from an ESX shell to see what's open. For reference:  (http://blogs.vmware.com/tp/files/vmware-management-with-vcli-5.0.pdf)[http://blogs.vmware.com/tp/files/vmware-management-with-vcli-5.0.pdf]

Comment: Are you able to do a regular icmp ping from the DR site to vCenter?  My suspicion is that the traffic is being blocked at the VPN/Firewall level, rather than at the vCenter server.

Comment: @CIA I will try that and actually, I will keep that for future references as well.  Thanks.

Comment: @1.618 Yes, I can, that was the weird part about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after finally getting someone knowledgeable from VMWare support, she took a look at the vCenter in question and found out that one of the VM related services wasn't running, that's why I was unable to **nmap ping** it.

See this **screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

I kind of figured it was something stupid on my end.  Thank you everyone for all your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Erm....this is an odd one.

What are you trying to achieve and why? Are you aware that vCenter itself uses both 80 and 443? you know that vCenter talks to its hosts via 902/903 right?

Have you seen [THIS](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2031843)?

Comment: It's a requirement for our disaster recovery software (Double Take) to use vCenter to gain access to esx host.  I have already had a conversation with Double Take about it and I was able to get to host directly (using Double Take) to write to, but we don't want to use root (and password for that matter), so it makes it either to use vCenter and manage it that way too.  Does it kind of make sense?